# multiply each element in array by 2 using 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to double each element in an array

```
let arr =  ['onions', 'tomatoes', 'etc'...';
```

with a for loop and keep getting `NaN` error...  I'm still learning so any advice would be appreciated.

I've tried for loop, `.map()`, and other methods, but just can't see the obvious problem...

```
let newIngr = tortSoup.filter(function(value, index, arr) {
  if (value !== 'onion' && value !== 'red pepper') {
    return value;
    console.log(newIngr);
  });       
}

let myReci = [];

for(var i = 0; i < newIngr.length; i++) {
  myReci[i] = newIngr[i] * 2;
}

console.log(myReci);
```

Expected: each array element multiped by two and returned:

```
['onions', tomatoes', 'garlic', 'fontina']
```

would become:

```
['onions', 'onions', 'tomoatoes', 'tomatoes', garlic, 'garlic', 'fontina', 'fontina']
```

Comment: `string` * 2 will not return 2 strings to you. it will return NaN

Comment: [Hint] : Look into using [`Array#push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) twice in your loop

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) and the spread operator:

```js
const array = ['onions', 'tomatoes', 'garlic', 'fontina'];

const result = array.reduce((acc, x) => ([...acc, x, x]), []);

console.log(result)
```

`Array.reduce` iterates over your input array and calls the callback for each element. This callback is given two arguments, the first is the output from the last iteration, and the second one is the current array item.

The callback here returns a new array composed of the previous result of the callback (spread into the new array with the spread operator `...`) and the current item repeated twice.

To start the reducing process, we also need an initial value, here we give an empty array, (last argument to `reduce`).

Here is a detailed description of the values of `acc` and `x` in the callback for the following reduction:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].reduce((acc, x) => ([...acc, x, x]), []);
```

1. `acc = [], x = 'a' => returns ['a', 'a']`
2. `acc = ['a', 'a'], x = 'b' => returns ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']`
3. `acc = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], x = 'c' => returns ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']`

Comment: As you can see user is new to programming. adding explanation to answer will do wonder to op and future readers to.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good point, I will add more explanations

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate over `input` array using `.map()`.
- Initialize new array using `Array()` constructor and filling it using `.fill()` method of arrays.
- Finally you can convert array of arrays to a single array using `.concat()` and spread operator.

```js
const input = ['onions', 'tomatoes', 'garlic', 'fontina'];

const dupeValues = (arr, factor) => [].concat(...arr.map(s => new Array(factor).fill(s)));

console.log(dupeValues(input, 2));
console.log(dupeValues(input, 3));
```

Comment: As you can see user is new to programming. adding explanation to answer will do wonder to op and future readers to.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your help.. I learned a ton from every response and  using figured it with the array.reduce() and spread operator... Thanks for your time...

Comment: For keeping it generic +1

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (not supported by IE/Edge):

```js
const array = ['onions', 'tomatoes', 'garlic', 'fontina'];

const result = array.flatMap(item => [item, item]);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JavaScript :

```js
const ingredients = [ 'onions', 'tomatoes', 'garlic', 'fontina' ]
const ingredientsToRemove = [ 'onions', 'red pepper' ]

// Using Array.reduce method
const doubleIngredients = ingredients.reduce(
  ( array, ingredient ) =>
  {
    // If the ingredient has to be removed, return the array
    // Else return the array with two times the current ingredient
    return ingredientsToRemove.includes( ingredient ) ?
      array
      :
      [ ...array, ingredient, ingredient ]      
  },
  []
)

console.log({ ingredients, doubleIngredients })
```

Answer (score 0):

***Well the problem here is***

***string * 2 will not return 2 strings to you. it will return `NaN`***

```js
console.log('test'* 2) //NaN
```

What you're trying to achieve can be done by `repeat` method.

```js
console.log('test '.repeat(2))
```

Your expected output can be achieved like this

```js
let arr = ['onions', 'tomatoes', 'garlic', 'fontina']
let output = arr.reduce((op,inp)=>(op.concat([inp,inp])),[])
console.log(output)
```